# Best known hidden constant in complexity of AKS sorting networks

Tags: reference-request

The famous AKS sorting network allows one to sort $N$ elements via a circuit composed out of comparator gates, where the circuit has size $\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$ and depth $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$.
The latest discussion of the hidden constants behind this construction that I could find were in the [Zig-Zag sorting paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.2777.pdf), where (if I correctly understood) the author states that $13 613 047$ is the currently best known constant.

**Question:**
Is this, as of 2020, still the best known hidden constant for a deterministic oblivious sorting algorithm with optimal complexity?

Comment: The Zig-Zag paper seems to say it isn’t $O(\log n)$ depth, so unfortunately I don’t think it applies as a solution to your question.

Comment: Oh yes Zig-Zag has depth $\mathcal{O}(n)$. It was just the latest paper which discussed the hidden constants behind AKS as well. Since this is already over 5 years ago, I was wondering whether the hidden constants improved (for AKS).